# How to whitelist IPs in .htaccess file? Is it compulsory to write ip list in bitween <Limit GET POST PUT> </Limit> directory?

Tags: whitelist

I want to allow only list of ips that need to be whitelisted. Not want to blacklist or deny any other ips list in .htaccess file.

So please help me for how to whitelist only allow IPs in .htaccess file?

Is it compulsory to write ip list in between   directory?

is it compulsory to add "order" statement, while i just want to set only allow ips list add. Not want to blacklist or deny any other ips list.

Comment: Why do you want to whitelist, if you don't want to deny other IPs?

Comment: because I want to allow other ips. There are same no. ips visits site. So site traffic generate from same ips and that why hosting server firewall block that ips. That actually not spam ips. So i want to whitelist (Allow) ip list in htaccess file.

Comment: i'm using cloudflare cdn for my site. They provide list of ips need to be whitelisted in your hosting server.